# MathJaX and phpbb 3.1 version

Tags: mathjax, phpbb3

Here is the issue. I want to integrate MathJaX into my phpbb 3.1 installation version but apparently placing the java script of mathjax in the overall_footer does not seem to do the trick. Instead I get an error message saying something about LeXer or something like that.

In the previous version 3.0 I did not have any problem implementing MathJaX in the overall_footer.html document. I did ask at phpbb.com for support but said that this is not a phpbb issue.

So, where do I need to place the script on my forum so that I get MathJaX support? I cannot place in the header either because the forum won't load in this case. Oh forgot to mention that if I implement it as BBcode it runs problem free but this is not the solution I want.